# Chef and MySql: Error setting data_dir

Tags: mysql, vagrant, chef-infra

I am trying to setup Mysql server 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 using Chef 12

It all goes fine till i try to set the data_dir to a custom value (It was working fine with the default value)

**[UPDATE_1]**
It seems that the location of the data directory is the problem, if I set the data_dir to anything other than the newly mounted partition, it works fine

for example:

```
data_dir '/var/data/mysql/master'
```

works fine, but the directory on the mounted partition does not work.

please note that the partition is mounted successfully and directories on the mounted file system are also created successfully.

Is there a problem in the mount resource definition? Is there something missing in mysql config? why i get that error when creating the data_dir in that location?

**[END_UPDATE_1]**

here is how my reciepe looks like:

```
mysql2_chef_gem 'default' do


client_version node[:application][:mysql_master][:version]
  action :install
end

user 'db_manager' do
  action :create
end

directory '/mnt/data/mysql' do
  owner 'db_manager'
  recursive true
  action :create
end


mount '/mnt/data/mysql' do
  device '/dev/sdb1'
  fstype 'ext4'
end


data_directory = "/mnt/data/mysql/master"
directory data_directory do
  owner 'db_manager'
  recursive true
  action :create
end

mysql_service node[:application][:mysql_master][:service_name] do
  run_user 'db_manager'
  data_dir data_directory
  port node[:application][:mysql_master][:bind_port]
  version node[:mysql][:version]
  initial_root_password node[:application][:mysql_master][:password]
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

I got the following error

```
    ==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:       
==> default: Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[master :create initial records]'
==> default:       
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:       
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default:       
==> default: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:       
==> default: ------------------------------------
==> default:       
==> default: Expected process to exit with [0, 1, 2], but received '141'
==> default: 
==> default:       
==> default: ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
==> default: 
==> default:       STDOUT: Installing MySQL system tables...
==> default:       STDERR: 2016-06-13 07:19:29 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 19198 ...
==> default:       ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
==> default:       Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" returned 141
==> default:       
==> default:       Resource Declaration:
==> default:       ---------------------
==> default:       # In /tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_base.rb
==> default:       
==> default:       158:         bash "#{new_resource.name} :create initial records" do
==> default:       159:           code init_records_script
==> default:       160:           umask '022'
==> default:       161:           returns [0, 1, 2] # facepalm
==> default:       162:           not_if "/usr/bin/test -f #{parsed_data_dir}/mysql/user.frm"
==> default:       163:           action :run
==> default:       164:         end
==> default:       165:       end
==> default:       
==> default:       Compiled Resource:
==> default:       ------------------
==> default:       # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_base.rb:158:in `block in <class:MysqlServiceBase>'
==> default:       
==> default:       bash("master :create initial records") do
==> default:         action [:run]
==> default:         retries 0
==> default:         retry_delay 2
==> default:         default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:         command "master :create initial records"
==> default:         backup 5
==> default:         returns [0, 1, 2]
==> default:         umask "022"
==> default:         code "        set -e\n        rm -rf /tmp/mysql-master\n        mkdir /tmp/mysql-master\n\n        cat > /tmp/mysql-master/my.sql <<-EOSQL\nUPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE user = 'root';\nDELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE USER LIKE '';\nDELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root' and host NOT IN ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost');\nFLUSH PRIVILEGES;\nDELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'test%';\nDROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test ;\nEOSQL\n\n       mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/etc/mysql-master/my.cnf --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql/master --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp\n       /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql-master/my.cnf --init-file=/tmp/mysql-master/my.sql --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp &\n\n       while [ ! -f /run/mysql-master/mysqld.pid ] ; do sleep 1 ; done\n       kill `cat /run/mysql-master/mysqld.pid`\n       while [ -f /run/mysql-master/mysqld.pid ] ; do sleep 1 ; done\n       rm -rf /tmp/mysql-master\n"
==> default:         interpreter "bash"
==> default:         declared_type :bash
==> default:         cookbook_name :tr_mysql
==> default:         not_if "/usr/bin/test -f /mnt/data/mysql/master/mysql/user.frm"
==> default:       end
==> default:       
==> default:       Platform:
==> default:       ---------
==> default:       x86_64-linux
==> default:       
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:30+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:     
==> default: Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_service[master]'
==> default:     
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:     
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
==> default:     
==> default: ------------------------------------
==> default:     
==> default: bash[master :create initial records] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_base.rb line 158) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 1, 2], but received '141'
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: STDOUT: Installing MySQL system tables...
==> default: 
==> default:     
==> default: STDERR: 2016-06-13 07:19:29 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 19198 ...
==> default: 
==> default:     ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
==> default:     Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" returned 141
==> default:     
==> default:     Resource Declaration:
==> default:     ---------------------
==> default:     # In /tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/tr_mysql/recipes/mysql_master.rb
==> default:     
==> default:      31: mysql_service node[:application][:mysql_master][:service_name] do
==> default:      32:   run_user 'db_manager'
==> default:      33:   data_dir data_directory
==> default:      34:   port node[:application][:mysql_master][:bind_port]
==> default:      35:   version node[:mysql][:version]
==> default:      36:   initial_root_password node[:application][:mysql_master][:password]
==> default:      37:   action [:create, :start]
==> default:      38: end
==> default:      39: 
==> default:     
==> default:     Compiled Resource:
==> default:     ------------------
==> default:     # Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/tr_mysql/recipes/mysql_master.rb:31:in `from_file'
==> default:     
==> default:     mysql_service("master") do
==> default:       action [:create, :start]
==> default:       updated true
==> default:       updated_by_last_action true
==> default:       retries 0
==> default:       retry_delay 2
==> default:       default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:       declared_type :mysql_service
==> default:       cookbook_name :tr_mysql
==> default:       recipe_name "mysql_master"
==> default:       run_user "db_manager"
==> default:       data_dir "/mnt/data/mysql/master"
==> default:       port "3306"
==> default:       version "5.6"
==> default:       initial_root_password "root"
==> default:       instance "master"
==> default:       run_group "mysql"
==> default:       charset "utf8"
==> default:     end
==> default:     
==> default:     Platform:
==> default:     ---------
==> default:     x86_64-linux
==> default:     
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:30+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:30+00:00] INFO: template[/etc/init.d/chef-client] sending restart action to service[chef-client] (delayed)
==> default: Recipe: chef-client::init_service
==> default:   * service[chef-client] action restart
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] INFO: service[chef-client] restarted
==> default: 
==> default:     - restart service service[chef-client]
==> default: 
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 68 resources updated in 05 minutes 15 seconds
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] ERROR: mysql_service[master] (tr_mysql::mysql_master line 31) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[master :create initial records] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_base.rb line 158) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 1, 2], but received '141'
==> default: ---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
==> default: STDOUT: Installing MySQL system tables...
==> default: STDERR: 2016-06-13 07:19:29 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 19198 ...
==> default: ---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
==> default: Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" returned 141
==> default: [2016-06-13T07:19:31+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

The content of the stacktrace file: /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
 is the following

```
Generated at 2016-06-13 07:19:31 +0000
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: mysql_service[master] (tr_mysql::mysql_master line 31) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: bash[master :create initial records] (/tmp/vagrant-chef/d6451ed70ba00b72836a85c4cb3f45a6/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_base.rb line 158) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 1, 2], but received '141'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
STDOUT: Installing MySQL system tables...
STDERR: 2016-06-13 07:19:29 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 19198 ...
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20160613-7634-ok63tn" returned 141
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.6/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:289:in `invalid!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.6/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:276:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb:56:in `shell_out!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider/execute.rb:62:in `block in action_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider/execute.rb:60:in `action_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider/script.rb:63:in `action_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:84:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:82:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider.rb:361:in `compile_and_converge_action'
(eval):2:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/provider.rb:144:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource.rb:596:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:69:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:97:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:84:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:82:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/runner.rb:96:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/client.rb:667:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/client.rb:662:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/client.rb:662:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/client.rb:701:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/client.rb:281:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application.rb:285:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application.rb:273:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application.rb:273:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application.rb:238:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application.rb:226:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:301:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:290:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:290:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:269:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.38/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:51:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:51:in `<main>'
```

So, what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but you should step-by-step create parent folder in /mnt first, then create child folder, ....

Comment: the `recursive true` do the trick, actually the directories created successfully

Comment: the mysql-cookboo do this for me using a template based on the value I pass to the data_dir method, I made an update, please have a look at it

Comment: your mysql server has /dev/sdb1 disk, hasn't it ?

Comment: yes, and the partition is mounted successfully and directories on the mounted file system are also created successfully.

Comment: so now, what's your problem? can you explain more ?

Comment: Is there a problem in the mount resource definition? Is there something missing in mysql config? why i get that error when creating the data_dir in that location?

Comment: If you add `set -x` to https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/blob/7f431ecfe27a166b8027a3df8969943274f6ef48/libraries/helpers.rb#L165 it will probably help show which command is failing. Alternatively if you don't want to fork the cookbook, add `ENV['SHELLOPTS'] = 'xtrace'` somewhere in another recipe.

Comment: OK,i did that.. the last command is `mysql_install_db --defaults-file=/etc/mysql-master/my.cnf --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql/master --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`